# does anyone know how to batch insert to azure table storage using post man

Tags: azure-table-storage

I would like to perform entity group transactions to azure table storage using postman. please let me know the sample request body to perform the batch operation. I tried to hit the endpoint using the sample request body mentioned in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/performing-entity-group-transactions) still no luck.

URL: [https://azautomationdiag.table.core.windows.net/$batch"?sp==SASTokenTest"](https://azautomationdiag.table.core.windows.net/$batch%22?sp==SASTokenTest%22)

Header: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgw9Z.png)

Parameters: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxiAl.png)

Body:

```
 `
--batch_f351702c-c8c8-48c6-af2c-91b809c651ce
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_8a28b620-b4bb-458c-a177-0959fb14c977  

--changeset_8a28b620-b4bb-458c-a177-0959fb14c977  
Content-Type: application/http  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


POST https://azautomationdiag.table.core.windows.net/InstalledApplications HTTP/1.1  
Content-Type: application/json  
Content-Length: [1322] 
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata  
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;  

{"PartitionKey":"Channel_19", "RowKey":"1", "Rating":9, "Text":".NET..."}  
--changeset_8a28b620-b4bb-458c-a177-0959fb14c977  
Content-Type: application/http  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


POST https://azautomationdiag.table.core.windows.net/InstalledApplications HTTP/1.1  
Content-Type: application/json  
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata  
Prefer: return-no-content  
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;  
  
{"PartitionKey":"Channel_19", "RowKey":"2", "Rating":9, "Text":"Azure..."}  
--changeset_8a28b620-b4bb-458c-a177-0959fb14c977  
Content-Type: application/http  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

--changeset_8a28b620-b4bb-458c-a177-0959fb14c977--
--batch_f351702c-c8c8-48c6-af2c-91b809c651ce
```

`
Response: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvfCC.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the details about your request (request URL, body etc.). Also tell us the issues you're running into. Unfortunately `no luck` doesn't tell us much :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, the request body should be like

```
--batch_guid
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_guid

--changeset_guid
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<your request>

--changeset_guid
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<your request> 
--changeset_guid--
--batch_guid--
```

For example

Request

```
https://andyprivate.table.core.windows.net?$batch{sastoken}
```

Header

```
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx
Accept: application/json; odata=minimalmetadata
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
x-ms-version: 2017-07-29
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_e4071276-6bca-459b-af6b-c18e5eb42106
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Connection:Keep-Alive
```

Request Body

```
--batch_e4071276-6bca-459b-af6b-c18e5eb42106
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_52c5f249-48de-4ae5-89e6-b288a26099f1

--changeset_52c5f249-48de-4ae5-89e6-b288a26099f1
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://andyprivate.table.core.windows.net/test HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
Content-Type: application/json
Prefer: return-no-content
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;

{"PartitionKey":"Channel_19", "RowKey":"1", "Rating":9, "Text":".NET..."} 
--changeset_52c5f249-48de-4ae5-89e6-b288a26099f1
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://andyprivate.table.core.windows.net/test HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
Content-Type: application/json
Prefer: return-no-content
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;

{"PartitionKey":"Channel_19", "RowKey":"2", "Rating":9, "Text":"Azure..."}  
--changeset_52c5f249-48de-4ae5-89e6-b288a26099f1
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST https://andyprivate.table.core.windows.net/test HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
Content-Type: application/json
Prefer: return-no-content
DataServiceVersion: 3.0;

{"PartitionKey":"Channel_19", "RowKey":"3", "Rating":4, "Text":"Java..."}  
--changeset_52c5f249-48de-4ae5-89e6-b288a26099f1--
--batch_e4071276-6bca-459b-af6b-c18e5eb42106--
```

[image]
[image]